# Disable symlink and mount path resolve in Mac

Tags: macos, symlink, symlink-traversal

In mac (el captain), when a file is selected by browsing through a symlink path that points to network or mount point, and you show the file info, then the network path or device path is retrieved instead.

example: 
if /nas is a symlink to nfs://nas/ifs/data, then the file info of /nas/projects will show by the system as:
nfs://nas/ifs/data/projects
then you cannot share this weird path with anybody else on windows or linux before you fix the weird information that meant to be kept hidden to the user for cleaner path.

So, is there a way I can disable this feature and mac and force it to always return the actual path regardless if this is a symlink or not?

Comment: Are you talking about in the Finder? Does it help to select Edit > Copy "<whatever>" as Pathname? (You have to hold down the Option key to see that menu item.)

Comment: Yea.. I mean the finder... some times I want to click command+i to get the file info to share the full path with someone on windows or linux in our same network... having underlying path resolved instead of the direct symlink path is annoying in this situation.